# Touch screen is not working properly after replacing LCD display and Touch screen

Tags: screen, hardware, touchscreen

I recently replaced LCD display and Touch screen of micromax canvas A116. but unfortunately my touch screen is not working properly. so my question is that is it because of
some hardware issue or should i require to hard reset my phone or should i do something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you replaced your LCD and Digitizer of the tablet may suggest that this will be a hardware problem. Assuming that the device was functional before the 'surgery'.
You might want to double check all the connectors of the digitizer and or display. When that is all 100% correct you can consider that the digitizer will be Dead on Arrival.
Good luck..

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there any connection between LCD and Digitizer? or is it both different entities ?

Comment: I dont know how your device looks on the inside or how the hardware is attached, usually the screen and digitizer have seperate flex cables which you plug in on the mainboard.
Assuming you recently replaced the LCD and Digitizer, you should know :)